# java - Check when a page changes

Tags: java, httprequest

I'm trying to create an app that alerts me when a page changes (for example when they publish new contents ecc).

My first attempt was get the page html, store it and compare this code with the new one. I used: [Simplest way to correctly load html from web page into a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381617/simplest-way-to-correctly-load-html-from-web-page-into-a-string-in-java)

My second attempt was using this: [How to check whether a website has been updated and send a email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881029/how-to-check-whether-a-website-has-been-updated-and-send-a-email)

But nothing worked because it alerts that pages as facebook.com (log in page) or google.com change every time I check (and it is impossible).

What can I do?

Comment: "_it alerts that pages as facebook.com or google.com change every time I check (and it is impossible)_" If I include a timestamp somewhere on my page it would flag as different on every page load. How do you know Google and Facebook don't do something similar?

Comment: Well that depends on the page, the content, the http features available (If-Modified-Since, ..).

Comment: Of course, it is possible and it depends on the service you use. I would suggest only to compare the content of the body tag of a page.

Comment: It seems you need to bypass the authentication, which is not that easy. It is better if you look for an api or RSS feed that the website is providing, which will makes things much cleaner, easier and reliable.